# creating dynamic groups for validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm quite new in jquery validation and I need your help in an easy subject.

I am validating a dynamic table. This table has a button which add rows. One of the fields is a percentage and I'm validating if the sum of percentages for all rows is 100%. But, I can't attach error messages or any invalidate classes to the percentage field. I read about groups, but I can't manage how can I a 'dynamic' group, because I can't know how many rows are there.
The row fields have a name like Percentage[0], Percentage[1] and an id generated by .NET MVC3.

Please, can you give me a hand with this? I'm sure I'm skipping any useful info, somewhere... Can anyone put me in the right way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards.

---

EDIT:

Sure, I'm sorry. Here is my code:

At this moment, I'm using class validations to get all fields I want, but now, I can't show the errors in a div. I want to show only one error, but validate all percentage fields at once.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$.validator.addMethod("checksum", function (value, element, params) {
    var sum = 0;
    $(params.elements).each(function (i, e) {
        sum = sum + parseInt($(e).val());
    });

    return sum == params.total;
}, $.format("The percentage fields must equal {1} "));

$.validator.addClassRules({ totalize: { checksum: { elements: ".totalize", total: 100}} });

$("#myform").validate({ errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
    if (element.hasClass("totalize")) {
        error.appendTo("#errors") 
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});

$(function () {

    var $clone = $('<tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="Person[].Name"></td><td><input type="text" value="" name="Person[].Percentage" class="totalize"></td></tr>');

    $("#AddPerson").on("click", function () {
        $clone.clone().appendTo("#people");
    });
});

</script>

<div class="percentages">

    <table class="">
        <caption>
            Percentages
        </caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>

                <th>
                    <button id="AddPerson" type="button">Add</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="people">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="Person[].Name">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="Person[].Percentage" class="totalize">
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="errors"> 
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) if you are dynamically adding inputs to your form.  Make sure your call the   validate() on your form (you were missing the form tags on your code with id="myForm").  Also, I added some 'improvements'.  [Check out the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vtT2T/) or review the following code:

```
/*I used an array instead of object literal in order to format your message.  The object literal hasn't working */
$.validator.addMethod("checksum", function (value, element, params) {
    var sum = 0;
    $(params[0]).each(function (i, e) {
        ///specify radix 10 and use || incase the value is empty
        sum += parseInt($(e).val(), 10) || 0;
    });
    return sum == params[1];
}, $.validator.format("The percentage fields must equal {1}"));
var totalize = {
    checksum: [".totalize", 100]
};
$.validator.addClassRules("totalize", totalize);
var valSettings = {
    onkeyup: true,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.hasClass("totalize")) {
            error.appendTo("#errors");
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
};


$(function () {

    $("#myForm").validate(valSettings);
    var $clone = $('<tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="Person[].Name"></td><td><input type="text" value="" name="Person[].Percentage" class="checksum totalize"></td></tr>');

    $("#AddPerson").on("click", function () {
        $clone.clone()
            .appendTo("#people")
            .find("input[name='Person[].Percentage']")
            .rules("add", totalize);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! So, Can I remove the $.validator.addClassRules("totalize", totalize); because is not longer needed.

Comment: But I want none of percentage fields become invalid with totalize rule, only show a message and avoid form submission, Does exist any way to attach 'general' rules for my entire table and not by field?

I need to show specific field errors for percentage fields at right and totalize errors at the bottom, how can I archieve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tistklehoff do you mean that you don't want the red bordering?  You can easily remove the CSS rule for the _.error_ class if that is what you mean.